# How to get readable classname and title from HWND handle? in WinApi c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using the following enumchild proc to get hwnd of each window, the problem is that i am unable to somehow detect any info from each hwnd so i can do what i want with the ones that are detected as the ones i need.

For example, how could i get window class name and the title of each window in the enum bellow?

I tried something like..

EDITED: copy pasted(if that helps)

```
TCHAR cName[MAX_PATH];

BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {


 TCHAR cName[MAX_PATH];
 GetClassName(hwnd, cName, _countof(cName));
  cout << cName << endl;

     return TRUE; 
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0, TEXT("reference"));
    EnumChildWindows(hwnd, EnumChildProc, 0);

    system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}
```

It just returns the hexadec handle info and every single time it is same, shouldnt the GetClassName func change the cName into new handle each time?

Also GetClassName function returns number of chars written to cName, i dont really see how this is useful to me? I need to get my cName in some readable format so i can do something like

**if(className == TEXT("classnameiamlookingfor" && hwndtitle = TEXT("thetitlethatinterestsme") DOSOMETHINGWITHIT();**

But all i get here is hexadec mess.

Comment: Did you try enabling debug symbols in linker options?

Comment: There's a rather obvious bug in your snippet.  Hard to believe it is real.  Copy and paste from your editor, don't type it in the post.  And don't compare strings with ==

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn't it Unicode build?

Check again with below:

```
TCHAR className[MAX_PATH];
GetClassName(hwnd, className, _countof(cName));
_tprintf(cName);
```

Comment: For TCHAR string compare use "_tcscmp(a, b) == 0"

Comment: wow thanks 9dan, it works i just need a way to put a linebreak with _tprintf() and if you would be so kind to tell me how to get a title in the same format that is useful for some comparison?

Comment: the title of hwnd i mean, and nvm stupid q about linebreak :eyeroll:

Comment: @Marko29: for TCHAR compiled with UNICODE output to std::wcout instead of std::cout.

Comment: Careful, never pass a variable format string to printf. Use `_tprintf("%s\n", className);` instead.

Comment: Alex Budovski:  I get this error C2664: 'wprintf' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [4]' to 'const wchar_t *'

Comment: `className or cName`?